# Question marks instead of Russian subtitles but only in ODBC connection and only through the browser

Tags: php, apache, odbc

I welcome all those willing to help,

I fell off my feet and I have no idea anymore:

I have a server with apache2 and php. I have a simple script that retrieves data, including data in Russian. Whatever encoding I wouldn't set in apache or php or even choose in the browser I always have question marks instead of subtitles. And now the two most important things.

The script fired in bash: php path/index.php displays everything correctly, so I assume it's not the fault of the bounce.

Through the client's browser I always have question marks

Manually call the Russian subtitle through an echo, displays correctly and from the client's browser and bash.

Where and what to look for, please point and help.

I'll just add that everywhere I set up this UTF-8, in php, apache, php file, header, in bash everything works, and through the browser just question marks but only in data from ODBC, rigidly pasting text in Russian nicely displays it and in php and browser.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Add:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "AAAКоллекция, вдохновленная картинами Климта<br><pre>";
 $dbh= new PDO('odbc:hanipol', '', '');
 $dbh->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
 $dbh->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
 $query = "call tlumacz@techjawt()";
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("$query");
 $stmt->execute();
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($row['JEZYK'] == 'RU')
     echo $row['TLUM'].'<br>';
 }
 unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
```

OR

```
$odbc =odbc_connect("hanipol",'','');
if (!$odbc) {
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $odbc);
}
$query = "call tlumacz@techjawt()";
$rs=odbc_exec($odbc,$query);
```

test: http://software.hanipol.com/admin/j.php

```
from bash:~# php j.php
from echo : AAAКоллекция, вдохновленная картинами Климта<br><pre>from odbc: Коллекция, вдохновленная картинами Климта<br>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your ODBC connection string.